# Open Input file dialog on element click , fireEvent Mootools equivalent of jQuery trigger

Tags: jquery, mootools

Trying to hide input file so I can style it for all browsers and would like to use js to fire the file upload dialog box

I was under the impression that `.fireEvent(eventType)` in mootools is same as `.trigger(eventType)` in jQuery

jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/KnqFj/1/

```
$('#trig_file').click(function(){
    console.log('click');
    $('#file').trigger('click');
});
```

mootools: http://jsfiddle.net/X6mqR/7/

```
$('trig_file').addEvent('click', function(){
    console.log('click');
    $('file').fireEvent('click');
});​​
```

but it does not seem to be same

any help is appreciated

Comment: odd: http://jsfiddle.net/X6mqR/15/ it does appear to fire the click event on `#file`, but not the choose file action associated with it.

Comment: just had a bit of a play around. Looks as though the mootools .fireEvent only fires event handlers that are attached by mootools with the addEvent, i.e. not native browser events. Just out of interest $('file').click() - seemed to work nicely. I don't know enough about mootools to tell you if that was ok to do?

Comment: strange I know , just looking other posts about it but it fires all other events just fine

Comment: nice find , yes .click() works fine http://jsfiddle.net/X6mqR/16/

Comment: just out of interest http://mootools.net/docs/core125/core/Element/Element.Event#Element:fireEvent - clause at the bottom 'This will not fire the DOM event'

Comment: nice find OJay , I just looked trough docs and cant find any info on ele.click(), very strange

Comment: @Benn - that's because the `click` / `onclick` attribute is a `DOM` method, not a MooTools-added one.

Comment: thank you Sean , makes sense now

Comment: @Benn, The implementation of the two libraires have a different paradigm. jQuery wraps up the DOM element/s that you are working with into a jQuery object. Mootools, similar to the prototype library, adds functions onto the actual DOM elements themselves, hence why .click() is not a mootools function, but a DOM element one as the obj returned by $('file') is a DOM element with mootool extensions, as opposed to $('#file') in jQuery returns a jQuery object with DOM elements in it (0 or more). Anyway,. though I might add what I found, because it interested me also.

Answer (score 4):

Just for everyone's reference ,  this can be used in order to style the browse button to your preference. You can hide the input file completely and fire event on any element.

jquery: http://jsfiddle.net/g9sry/3/

```
$('#trig_file').click(function(){
    console.log('click');
    $('#file').trigger('click');
});​
```

mootools: http://jsfiddle.net/X6mqR/17/

```
$('trig_file').addEvent('click', function(){
    console.log('click');
    $('file').click();
});​
```

I tested in , 
FF
IE7 and Up
Opera
Safari
Chrome
but we still did not find out why is it that the fireEvent is not same as trigger in jquery